# How to make subplots in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, subplot

I am trying to make subplots. 
I call many columns from a dataframe, turn them into array and plot them.
I want to plot them in 4 rows, 2 columns. But I only get 1 column (you can check the image). What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
  for column in df3:  #I call the dataframe
      data=df3[column].values  #Turn it into an array

      fig = plt.figure()
      plt.subplot (4,2,1) #I want 4 rows and 2 columns
      ax,_=plot_topomap(data, sensors_pos, cmap='viridis', vmin=0, vmax=100, show=False)
      plt.title("KNN" + " " + column) #This is the title for each subplot
      fig.colorbar(ax)
      plt.show
```

[image]

Comment: "But it does not work" is not a sufficient problem description. Please read [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [MCVE].

Comment: People will need to download a neuroscience library to use the plot_topomap and a file with the electrodes positions. So I do not know how to make this complete.

Comment: You can build a [MCVE] either top-down or bottom-up. I don't know which one is better in this case, since you do not tell us, what the problem is.

Comment: I want a 4 rows and 2 columns plot. But I just  get 1 column with all the plots and they have become small.

Comment: Is the `plot_topomap` command you are using the [`mne.viz.plot_topomap`](http://martinos.org/mne/stable/generated/mne.viz.plot_topomap.html) from mne?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things which might cause problems in your code and it's hard to find a solution without knowing the complete code.

In your code you create several figures. However, you really want one single figure. So the figure needs to be creates outside the loop.

Then you want to create subplots, so in every loop step you need to tell matplotlib to which subplot it should plot. This can be done by `ax = fig.add_subplot(4,2,n)` where n is a number which you increase in every run of the loop.

Next you call `plot_topomap`. But how would `plot_topomap` know what to plot where? You need to tell it, by supplying the keyword argument `axes = ax`.

Finally try to set a colorbar, with the return image as argument to the axes `ax`.

Of course I cannot test the following code, but it might do what you want, in case I interpreted everything well.

```
n = 1
fig = plt.figure()
for column in df3:  #I call the dataframe
    data=df3[column].values  #Turn it into an array

    ax = fig.add_subplot(4,2,n) #I want 4 rows and 2 columns
    im,_ = plot_topomap(data, sensors_pos, cmap='viridis', vmin=0, vmax=100, show=False, axes=ax)
    ax.set_title("KNN" + " " + column) #This is the title for each subplot
    fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
    n+=1
```